# Get rid of warning for external data connection

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

In Excel 2011 for Mac, I'm using an external data link to collect data from a CSV file generated by a third party application. The CSV is continuously filled, so I want to update the data every time I open the Excel spreadsheet. I set the option of the data link accordingly.

My problem : every time I open the spreadsheet I have a security warning that disables the data connection, and I have to manually re-enable the connection.

How can I get rid of this message?

To be clear: I need the data connection in my spreadsheet, I just don't want to be bothered by a warning message

Comment: can you post the security warning for us?

Comment: I don't have my Mac right now for a screen capture. It's a yellow bar under the ribbon saying "Security Warning. Data connections have been disabled." and a button to re-enable them.

Comment: Is the document and the location of the data connection included in the trust center?

Comment: @CharlieRB I couldn't find any _Trust Center_ in Office 2011 for Mac. Both files (the spreadsheet and the CSV are in the same folder on my local harddrive).

Comment: Sorry, I don't have that version, so I am not exactly sure what you do/don't have as far as feature menus. From what I've been able to find about your version, there isn't a way to get rid of the warning without removing the connection.

Comment: Yup, me neither, that's why I ask the question here.

Comment: I am afraid that the problem above is still valid for Excel 2016 for Mac - there's no Trust Center in it too. :(

Comment: Could you create a macro that creates the connection in the `Workbook_Open` event? You could remove the connection in the `Workbook_BeforeClose` event so you don't get the warning next time. The first time you open the file, you should be asked if you trust the macros in the file. In Windows, that will only show up the first time if you tell it to trust the document. It may or may not work that way on Mac.